# How to solve [ERROR] TypeError: dep.getModuleEvaluationSideEffectsState is not a function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, github-actions, docusaurus

I have created a docusaurus project. It was working fine. I added material ui search bar in the landing page. I am using github actions to deploy the project(CI/CD). Now when i push the code, iam getting this error.

```
[ERROR] TypeError: dep.getModuleEvaluationSideEffectsState is not a function
    at NormalModule.getSideEffectsConnectionState (/github/workspace/website/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:1126:23)
    at /github/workspace/website/node_modules/webpack/lib/optimize/SideEffectsFlagPlugin.js:244:19
    at Hook.eval [as call] (eval at create (/github/workspace/website/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:19:10), <anonymous>:12:16)
    at Hook.CALL_DELEGATE [as _call] (/github/workspace/website/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:14:14)
    at Compilation.seal (/github/workspace/website/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:2804:42)
    at /github/workspace/website/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:1187:20
    at /github/workspace/website/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:2757:4
    at _next2 (eval at create (/github/workspace/website/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:35:1)
    at eval (eval at create (/github/workspace/website/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:71:1)
    at /github/workspace/website/node_modules/webpack/lib/FlagDependencyExportsPlugin.js:385:11
```

I am not sure how to solve this. I have also attached package.json file.

```html
{
  "scripts": {
    "examples": "docusaurus-examples",
    "start": "docusaurus start",
    "build": "docusaurus build",
    "serve": "docusaurus serve",
    "publish-gh-pages": "docusaurus-publish",
    "write-translations": "docusaurus-write-translations",
    "version": "docusaurus-version",
    "rename-version": "docusaurus-rename-version",
    "swizzle": "docusaurus swizzle",
    "deploy": "docusaurus deploy",
    "docusaurus": "docusaurus"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=16.14.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@azure/msal-browser": "^2.28.0",
    "@azure/msal-react": "^1.4.4",
    "@docusaurus/core": "^2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@docusaurus/plugin-client-redirects": "^2.1.0",
    "@docusaurus/plugin-content-docs": "^2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@docusaurus/preset-classic": "^2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.10.4",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.10.4",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.18",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.4",
    "@mui/material": "^5.10.8",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "chart.js": "^3.8.0",
    "clsx": "^1.1.1",
    "docker": "^1.0.0",
    "docusaurus": "^1.14.7",
    "docusaurus-lunr-search": "^2.1.15",
    "docusaurus-pdf": "^1.2.0",
    "docusaurus2-dotenv": "^1.4.0",
    "env-cmd": "^10.1.0",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.4.0",
    "react-chartjs-2": "^4.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-icons": "^4.4.0",
    "react-markdown-editor-lite": "^1.3.2",
    "react-paginate": "^8.1.3",
    "react-player": "^2.10.1",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1"
  }
}
```

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Check this: https://github.com/mrsteele/dotenv-webpack/issues/275#issuecomment-952102800

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you using the plugin `docusaurus2-dotenv`?

We found the same problem here, and the root cause is this plugin. We remove this plugin from the package.json and from the docusaurus.config.js. We replaced it inside the `docusaurus.config.js` with the plugin `docusaurus-plugin-dotenv`, like this:

```js
// Before
plugins: 
[
    // Other plugins
    ['docusaurus2-dotenv', { systemvars: true }],
]
```

```js
// After
plugins: 
[
    // Other plugins
    [
      'docusaurus-plugin-dotenv',
      {
          path: "./.env", 
          systemvars: true, 
      }
    ]
]
```

This error occurs because the plugin 'docusaurus2-dotenv' is depreciated, although the docusaurus documentation itself recommends using it.

After removing it from our project, we noticed that even some vulnerabilities have gone away.

Here's the link of the new plugin: [docusaurus-plugin-dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/docusaurus-plugin-dotenv)